# Hibernate Exception: Pre-bound JDBC Connection found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have the following problem:

In a multi user spring hibernate web application we encounter the following exception. When checking the logging it happens at multiple places. I googled around, also checked Stackoverflow, but I can't find a solution:

> Pre-bound JDBC Connection found! HibernateTransactionManager does not
>   support running within DataSourceTransactionManager if told to manage
>   the DataSource itself. It is recommended to use a single
>   HibernateTransactionManager for all transactions on a single
>   DataSource, no matter whether Hibernate or JDBC access.

I read it might be a configuraton problem, but I don't see what's wrong so I'll include the hibernate configuration:

```
<!-- pooled datasource -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource" depends-on="poolableConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="pool"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="ds" class="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource">
    <property name="serverName">
        <value>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</value>
    </property>
    <property name="databaseName">
        <value>xxx</value>
    </property>
    <property name="portNumber">
        <value>50000</value>
    </property>
    <property name="user">
        <value>xxx</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>xxx</value>
    </property>
    <property name="driverType">
        <value>4</value>
    </property>
    <property name="allowNextOnExhaustedResultSet">
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property name="deferPrepares">
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="pool" class="org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool">
    <property name="minIdle">
        <value>5</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxActive">
        <value>50</value>
    </property>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis">
        <value>90000</value>
    </property>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis">
        <value>30000</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.DataSourceConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <ref bean="ds"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="poolableConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg index="0"><ref bean="dsConnectionFactory"/></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1"><ref bean="pool"/></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="2"><null/></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="3"><value>SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1</value></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="4"><value>false</value></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="5"><value>true</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="mappingLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:aaa/bbb/Ccc.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>classpath:aaa/bbb/Cdd.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>classpath:aaa/bbb/Eee.hbm.xml</value>                
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
           <value>aaa.bbb.Fff</value>
           <value>aaa.bbb.Ggg</value>   
           <value>aaa.bbb.Hhh</value>
        </list>
   </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">be.camco.po.persistency.hibernate.dialect.MyCustomDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">20</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- open session in view -->
<bean name="openSessionInViewInterceptor" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="hibernateSessionFactory"/>
    </property>
    <!-- flush auto =1, 0 = never-->
    <property name="flushMode">
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction manager for a single Hibernate SessionFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="hibernateSessionFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

For those who wonder what hibernate verion is being used; on deployment the following shows up in the log:

> [Version] Hibernate Annotations 3.2.1.GA
>
> INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.3.1.GA

Spring 3.2.4 is being used and spring security 3.1.4

Here is a stacktrace. The exception does occur on several occasions; I can't reproduce the exception; it seems to just happen sometime. In the stacktrace I included logging from before the exception with "Pre-bound JDBC Connection...", but I do not know if they are related:

```
> 2015-07-23 14:53:45,734 ERROR [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils] TransactionSynchronization.afterCompletion threw exception
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$ValueIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.afterTransactionCompletion(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.afterTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:450)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionSynchronization.afterCompletion(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:199)
    ...
2015-07-23 14:53:45,736 ERROR [STDERR] org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@4acab4eb] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@6c164690] bound to thread [http-10.249.0.32-443-4]
2015-07-23 14:53:45,736 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:541)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,737 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,737 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,737 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,737 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,737 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,737 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,737 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,737 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,737 ERROR [STDERR]  at be.camco.po.BusinessFacade$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$100126ee.toJSON(<generated>)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,737 ERROR [STDERR]  at be.camco.po.web.controller.ShipmentController.toListView(ShipmentController.java:200)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,737 ERROR [STDERR]  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor829.invoke(Unknown Source)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,737 ERROR [STDERR]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,737 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,737 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.invokeNamedMethod(MultiActionController.java:471)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,737 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.handleRequestInternal(MultiActionController.java:408)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,737 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,737 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,737 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at be.camco.po.web.filter.MenuFilter.doFilter(MenuFilter.java:28)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,738 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,739 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,739 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,739 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,739 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,739 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,739 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,739 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,739 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,739 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,739 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,739 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,739 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,739 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,739 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,739 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,739 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,739 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,739 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,739 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,739 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,739 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,740 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@4acab4eb] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@6c164690] bound to thread [http-10.249.0.32-443-4]
2015-07-23 14:53:45,740 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:189)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,740 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:532)
2015-07-23 14:53:45,740 ERROR [STDERR]  ... 65 more
2015-07-23 14:56:20,645 ERROR [STDERR] org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: Pre-bound JDBC Connection found! HibernateTransactionManager does not support running within DataSourceTransactionManager if told to manage the DataSource itself. It is recommended to use a single HibernateTransactionManager for all transactions on a single DataSource, no matter whether Hibernate or JDBC access.
2015-07-23 14:56:20,646 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:427)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,646 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,646 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,646 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,647 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,647 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,647 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,647 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,647 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,648 ERROR [STDERR]  at be.camco.po.BusinessFacade$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$100126ee.findProductByCode(<generated>)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,648 ERROR [STDERR]  at be.camco.po.web.controller.ProductController.formBackingObject(ProductController.java:616)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,648 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.getErrorsForNewForm(AbstractFormController.java:361)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,648 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.showNewForm(AbstractFormController.java:341)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,648 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.handleRequestInternal(AbstractFormController.java:281)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,648 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,648 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,648 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,649 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,649 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,649 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,649 ERROR [STDERR]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,649 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,649 ERROR [STDERR]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,649 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,649 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,649 ERROR [STDERR]  at be.camco.po.web.filter.MenuFilter.doFilter(MenuFilter.java:28)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,649 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,650 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,650 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,650 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,650 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,650 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,650 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,650 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,650 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,650 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,650 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,650 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,651 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,651 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,651 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,651 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,651 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,651 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,651 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,651 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,651 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,651 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,651 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,651 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,652 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,652 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,652 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,652 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,652 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,652 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,652 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,652 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,652 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,652 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,652 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,652 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,653 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
2015-07-23 14:56:20,653 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: do you have StackTrace for that message or is it a simple error/warning log  message? and: Which Spring/Hibernate version is used in you're setup? it seems hibernate 3.x?

Comment: I included answers to your questions in my post

Comment: in the cases that you get this exception , is the connection pool starved or it does throw it anytime anycase? cause maybe it's a pool's configuration problem

Comment: how do I check this?

Comment: The message apparently says that you are trying to use Spring or other framework to manage transactions while defining and managing  Datasources within Hibernate, so hibernate complaints about this. Have you tried to define datasources outside hibernate, In Spring or the application container?

Comment: I don't think so, no

Comment: if you are using log4j to log info , then open the log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager , to check whether its opening/releasing the connections in a proper way and also try to log in the most used query , which connection is being used by the settingsFactory , cause it may be a concurrent issue because you try to submit two transactions at the same time via the same connection , and apparently your driver or your DB does not allow that

Comment: Your code is not complete and has typos. For example, bean "pool" has no necessary reference to "poolableConnectionFactory" bean. Or stacktrace does not match to spring source code at version 3.2.4 (several spring jars in classpath?). I mean that  probably there is not enough information to solve your issue.

Comment: I copy pasted above xml configuration. I did adjust a few lines, but only to shorten it. I don't see any typo's. My application compiles, deploys and works.

Comment: @Tom Are you sure you exclude old spring version dependency (3.0.7) for spring-security? Please check WEB-INF/lib folder in compiled war file.

Comment: in the WEB-INF/lib folder I have: spring-security-config-3.1.4.jar, spring-security-core-3.1.4.jar, spring-security-taglibs-3.1.4.jar, spring-security-web-3.1.4.jar. No other spring-security jars

Comment: @user1516873 means that spring-security 3.1.4 has spring 3.0.7 as a dependency. So may be your lib contains both spring 3.2.4 and spring 3.0.7.

Comment: well, I only have spring...3.2.4 jars, spring-security...3.1.4 jars and spring-hibernate3-2.0.8.jar. No 3.0.7 jar

Comment: spring-hibernate3-2.0.8.jar - that's the problem )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I consider your code is not complete to solve your issue uniquely: there is no implied relation between `pool` and `poolableConnectionFactory`, not matching line numbers for spring version 3.2.4 (eg. `HibernateTransactionManager.java` at line 532 doesn't have the call to `TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource()` and so on).

I didn't find `<tx:annotation-driven/>` declaration in your config. And you use annotation driven transaction in `ProductController.formBackingObject()` method.

So my guess is your case is [described here](https://doctorjw.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/spring-and-pre-bound-jdbc-connection-found/).

EDIT: `HibernateTransactionManager` calls `bindResource()` at line 532 in spring version 2.0.8. As you pointed in comment application class path contains `spring-hibernate3-2.0.8.jar`, but `spring-orm-3.2.4.jar` should be used instead.

Comment: I have an xml file in the WEB-INF folder with following line: <context:annotation-config />

Comment: poolableConnectionFactory has a reference to pool as you can see in the xml in my question

Comment: printing SpringVersion.getVersion() in a startuplistener results in: 3.2.4.RELEASE

Comment: Yes, I agree about poolableConnectionFactory (not quite clear link). But I adviсe you to double-check annotation-driven / annotation-config, because they are not equivalent. From the documetation for annotation-config: "Note: This tag does not activate processing of Spring's `@Transactional` or EJB3's `@TransactionAttribute` annotation. Consider the use of the <tx:annotation-driven> tag for that purpose".

Comment: I do not use annotations for transactions; I use aop:<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="get*" propagation="NEVER"/>
            <tx:method name="set*" propagation="NEVER"/>
            <tx:method name="find*"/>
            <tx:method name="check*"/>
            <tx:method name="*"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

Comment: how do you conclude I use annotation driven transaction in ProductController.formBackingObject()?

Comment: There is `TransactionInterceptor` in your stacktrace above `formBackingObject()` method. Usually this means annotation using. The use of AOP is quite rare... Moreover creating transaction for every method (`<tx:method name="*"/>`) is rather heavy for application (with large count of beans). Can you share your application log from startup time + couple of minutes with info level for spring?

Comment: I'll try; I cannot append more to my post, since it's almost too long

Comment: Threre are many web services to share files: dropbox, filedropper, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86705/discussion-between-svaor-and-tom).

Comment: I hope you're right about spring-hibernate3-2.0.8.jar; I'll try and replace it tomorrow

Comment: I replaced the jar; It compiles and works. I can't really tell if this solved the problem since the exception only occurred once every week or so, but I'll update this post when I know more. Many thanks!

Comment: A previous transaction exception lead to the same exception. After going to Spring ticket - https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9496 , went through the whole server logs, get rid of that another exception, and never encountered this problem. The comments in the Spring ticket helped identifying that the issue was somewhere else.